You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry dadhich
I'm writing a paper in the Springer Nature template:
https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support
I'm receiving the following message:
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry dadhich
dadhich is the bibkey for the following reference:
@inproceedings{dadhich,
  title    = {Electromagnetic propulsion system for spacecrafts 
              using geomagnetic fields and superconductors},
  month    = {01},
  author   = {Dadhich, Anang and Schaffner, Grant},
  booktitle= {54th AIAA Aerospace Sciences Meeting},
  pages    = {0481},
  year     = {2016}
}

It also warns me that the problem happens in the .bst file at line 1702. I don't understand that much about macros, so if someone could help me, I will be truly grateful.
I tried to insert the .bst code along with this text; however, Stack Exchange doesn't allow making questions with more than 30000 words, and with the .bst code it was over than 40000 words. If anyone give me an idea how to bypass this, I guess it will be better for everyone.

Perhaps you are missing some fields. Try adding the editor field to your bib entry.

What happens if you (a) change the entry type from @inproceedings to @inbook and (b) replace month = {01} with month = jan and then perform a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more)?

I can confirm that inproceedings requires an editor field, but the style does funny things if one is provided: it adds it to the list of authors, for instance. The bib style is definitely buggy.
